# How to start a docker container under recent systemd?

Tags: docker

I have on a system old docker containers (created from specific images and started viua `docker start ...`). They were not used for quite some time (but were fully functional) and the server went though several updates, including having the latest `systemd`.

I need to start one of the existing docker containers, it fails to start and `docker logs` show et the end :

```
(...)
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:53: mounting \\\"cgroup\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay/b704b2f3c746eff3216f33d08435dccb723f09492347ea997164ef7b6669f3f4/merged\\\" at \\\"/sys/fs/cgroup\\\" caused \\\"no subsystem for mount\\\"\""
```

This issue is probably linked to a [conflict between docker and systemd](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/28109) but the solutions used there are not usable (I cannot modify the start parameters of host server and `docker run -v ...` applies to starting an image, as opposed to a container).

I do not know docker much, so **is there a way to `run` a container and manually mount `/sys/fs/cgroup` ?**

Comment: Have a look at this http://serverfault.com/questions/824975/systemctl-failed-to-get-d-bus-connection-operation-not-permitted/825027#825027

Comment: @13nilux: I mentioned in my question the `docker run` solution but what I have is a container, so I need to `start`it (and not `run`, whihcis for an image) - at least as far as I understand

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do that. You have to build the image properly. Just in case let's wait for someone to answer.

Comment: @13nilux: this container was fully functional before. It is the upgrade of `systemd` on the host which messed things up (not with the container but with docker / systemd interaction).